# Is there a way to set an android activities attributes conditionally?

Tags: android, attributes, android-activity, xamarin.android, monocross

In my Android application I have an activity where I've been using [Activity(NoHistory=true)] to keep the activity from appearing on the activity stack.

Now I'd like to make it conditional - sometimes it should be on the activity stack so the user can press Back to return to it from a subsequent screen; sometimes it shouldn't. Is there a way to "decorate" an activity conditionally or must I write some code to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't see such property/getter/setter in orginal android doc so i don't think if it will work ... anyway if you know that next in order activity will should run without apearing in history you can start it with flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for intent flags that can be set like the one below ? You could use that to start an activity and set the flag conditionally.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

Comment: That was meant to be an example. I've corrected the flag to FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY.